# C# WPF мыло в рамке TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего один край TabItem замыленный? Проблема не в шаблоне / стиле а в соседстве с другими контролами походу (тот же шаблон в другом месте замыленный слева а снизу нормальный)

Comment: RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" помог

Comment: Почему не в ответ?